# Should I use rafter baffles between every rafter . I have 2 roof vents now on a 20'x22' roof with 2x8 trusses. I was planning on using R19

Tags: insulation

I have a 20'x22' vaulted roof 24 inch on center with 2 roof vents. I was planning on using 23"x 6" R19 single face insulation between the 2x8 rafters. Do I need to use rafter baffles between each rafter the entire length or just between the rafters where the roof vents are.

Comment: This is an uninsulated garage roof I am planning on insulating

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. So, you have two soffit vents, or are they some other kind of vent? (A diagram would help.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.